# tsc ts/game.ts --out has not file output

Tags: windows, typescript, webstorm

I am trying

```
tsc ts/game.ts  --out test.js --module amd
```

on my typescript project in webstorm but the conole doesn't show any error and no test.js file is output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `--out` with `--module amd`. You either use external modules (amd) OR you combine your JS into one file.

Just run :

```
tsc ts/game.ts  --out test.js
```

More: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1